# Como borrar caracteres en consola de python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, consola, python-2.x

Algo como en java que creo es con un `\b` pero en python

Comment: Intentar con `write('\b')` o `write('\b \b')`

Answer (score 3):

En python27 puedes usar \b en una string y te borra el carácter anterior.

```
print "cara\bcter\b "
```

> Resultado en cmd o en la consola de python:
>   carcte

Comment: ¡No conocía este truco!